# Reading url arguments to run a python script

Tags: python-3.x, url, handler, web-deployment

I have a python file lets say myfile.py and I want to run it by a url .lets say www.abc.com/argument. This argument needs to be read within the python script. For eg. if the argument is www.abc.com/boy, then boy is my argument and my python code should be able to read this argument and then use it as a input parameter to run my code futher. How to achieve it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at one of python's web development platforms, such as [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) or [django](https://www.djangoproject.com). With them you could write web server that will run a piece of code every tome a url is called.

For example:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/abc")
def hello():
    print("The code here will run each time /abc is called")
    return "Hello World!"

app.run()
```

If you want to run a particular file each time the url is called, you could wrap the code in this file into a function, then use it here..

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I have achieved some part of it.
The real scenario is that I have two different website  data in a single table in mongodb.
For selecting data for a particualr website I have to filter out on basis of an id.
Now I have my python script in bitbucket and a url to hit it.
Now I want to pass an argument in the url which is my website guid.
My task is that how i read the url and get the url argument to get the website id .
I want to do it in the same script.

Comment: I can't undarstand the problem you are facing, are you recieving request, or sending one, and what is the connection to MongoDB?(It would be helpful if you add at least part of the script you are trying to create..)